# Finding b'\x00' in byte object string

Tags: python, arrays, find

I have this byte string:

```
b'#T\x005Q\x01\x00\x01_\x97\x013\xee\x1e\x00\x00\xcf\xd5\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B1:0,B2:0,B3:0\x00\x1081\x00\xf7\xac'
```

when I run the following code:

```
data = b'#T\x005Q\x01\x00\x01_\x97\x013\xee\x1e\x00\x00\xcf\xd5\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B1:0,B2:0,B3:0\x00\x1081\x00\xf7\xac'

selectable = data[32:data.find(b'\x00')]

print(selectable)
```

it should return:

```
b'B1:0,B2:0,B3:0'
```

but instead it returns:

```
b' '
```

Could anyone help me to figure out why?

Comment: Are you trying to find the *next* `\x00` after position 32? Because the first one is at position 2, so you’re doing `data[32:2]`. (If so: take a look at `help(bytes.find)`!)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
selectable = data[32:data.find(b'\x00',32)]
```

specify second parameter in find from where you want to start

you can refer here
[Python Find tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm)